# Media Query ONLY for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to ONLY change the CSS styling on Internet Explorer 10 >. I am using Media Query but it doesn't work.

I have inspected IE and the media query line with the change appear in the CSS file but for some reason it doesn't work.

What should I do in order to ONLY change my css style on IE?

```css
//// MEDIA QUERY ///
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  body {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

```html
<body>

  <div> HELLO </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What you would need instead is a feature detect for high contrast, too bad CSS feature detection does not yet work in IE( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40supports ), you could do the feature detection in JavaScript and set an appropriate classname.

Comment: Please change your title and body text. From the comments it is clear that you want this to work in *Edge* which is different from IE.

Comment: well when I mean Edge I mean IE and Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just declare it little different and it will work.

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {..}
```

you had double declaration after comma. tested it in IE11 and it works

```css
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  body {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}

@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  body {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div> HELLO </div>
```

Comment: Hello. I've just tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried with Microsoft Edge and I cannot see the red background. (I have copied and pasted your code example)

Comment: ohh,, this is for IE10-11 for Edge you need diff wrapping. I't works in Edge, try to refresh page and test

Comment: Yes now works in both! IE and Edge. Thank you very much!